# Testing significance of groups formed by classification tree leafs

Tags: statistical-significance, cart

I used mvpart to produce a classification tree (response variables concerning travel behaviour, explain variables are socio-demographic). In the output I can see the averages of the travel behaviour variables for the different segments formed by the tree. Is there a way to test if these differences are statistical significant different from each other?

Note: In the output I only see the summed SME, nog SE for every travel behaviour variable.

Comment: This is mostly irrelevant -- tree is not supposed to divide object into independent groups but just to make a good model. You are probably looking for *clustering*.

Answer (score 2):

Preliminary comment: I think if you build trees with `rpart` or `mvpart` you want to have the nonparametric nature that comes along with them. Hence you would want to use something nonparametric to test the differences in mean or some location parameter.

What you could try is to treat the partitioning as if it was given and proceed treating the segments as groups. Then the problem reduces to a $k$-group comparison of mean or other location parameter, with the test of your choice (e.g. a one-factor ANOVA or a Kruskal-Wallis procedure). This test, and I can't stress this enough, will be conditional on the overall tree partition.

Perhaps a bit more elegant then the crude "use the partitions as factor levels" approach would be if you already build your tree based on conditional inference. The function `party::ctree` allows to do that. It uses a nonparametric linear test statistic to decide whether to split, hence locally the difference between the two daughter nodes will be significant (which then traverses down the tree independently of the other branch, so there is no guarantee that globally all differences are significant).